# build method runs before initState finishes

Tags: flutter

I'm trying to make a weather app with Flutter. But for some reason, the build() method runs before the initState() method finishes. The thing is, all the state variables are initialized using the setState() method inside the initState(), whose variables are to be used in build() method. I guess the problem is that Flutter is trying to access those state variables before the setState() method, which keeps throwing me the error: A non-null String must be provided to a Text widget. I know these codes are too long to read. But I'd appreciate it if you could help me with this.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import "package:climat/screens/LoadingScreen.dart";
import "package:climat/screens/MainScreen.dart";
import "package:climat/screens/SearchScreen.dart";

void main() {
  runApp(
    MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData(
        fontFamily: "Open Sans",
      ),
      title: "Climat",
      initialRoute: "/",
      onGenerateRoute: (RouteSettings routeSettings) {
        dynamic routes = <String, WidgetBuilder>{
          "/": (context) => LoadingScreen(),
          "/index": (context) => MainScreen(),
          "/search": (context) => SearchScreen(),
        };
        WidgetBuilder builder = routes[routeSettings.name];
        return MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => builder(context));
      },
    ),
  );
}
```

```
import "package:flutter/material.dart";
import "package:flutter_spinkit/flutter_spinkit.dart";

import "package:climat/services/GeolocatorHelper.dart";
import "package:climat/services/NetworkHelper.dart";

import "package:climat/utilities/constants.dart";

class LoadingScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _LoadingScreenState createState() => _LoadingScreenState();
}

class _LoadingScreenState extends State<LoadingScreen> {
  Future<void> getWeatherData() async {
    Map<String, double> coordinates = await GeolocatorHelper().getGeoData();
    final NetworkHelper networkHelper = NetworkHelper(
        uri:
            "$endPoint&lat=${coordinates["latitude"]}&lon=${coordinates["longitude"]}");
    final dynamic data = await networkHelper.getData();
    return await Navigator.pushNamed(context, "/index", arguments: data);
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    this.getWeatherData();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Climat"),
      ),
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Center(
          child: SpinKitRing(
            color: Colors.redAccent,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

```
import "package:flutter/material.dart";

import "package:climat/services/WeatherHelper.dart";
import "package:climat/services/NetworkHelper.dart";

import "package:climat/utilities/constants.dart";

class MainScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MainScreenState createState() => _MainScreenState();
}

class _MainScreenState extends State<MainScreen> {
  Color backgroundColor;
  String cityName;
  int temperature;
  String status;
  String image;
  int minTemperature;
  int maxTemperature;
  int humidity;

  Future<void> updateUI({String userInput = null}) async {
    dynamic weatherData;
    if (userInput == null) {
      weatherData = ModalRoute.of(context).settings.arguments;
    } else {
      final NetworkHelper networkHelper =
          NetworkHelper(uri: "$endPoint&q=$userInput");
      weatherData = await networkHelper.getData();
    }
    final int weatherCode = weatherData["weather"][0]["id"];
    final WeatherHelper weatherHelper = WeatherHelper(
      weatherCode: weatherCode,
    );
    setState(() {
      this.backgroundColor = weatherHelper.getBackgroundColor();
      this.cityName = weatherData["name"];
      this.temperature = weatherData["main"]["temp"].toInt();
      this.status = weatherHelper.getWeatherStatus();
      this.minTemperature = weatherData["main"]["temp_min"].toInt();
      this.maxTemperature = weatherData["main"]["temp_max"].toInt();
      this.humidity = weatherData["main"]["humidity"];
      this.image = weatherHelper.getWeatherImage();
    });
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    this.updateUI();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: this.backgroundColor,
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Climat"),
      ),
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Center(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
            children: [
              Text(
                this.cityName,
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 24.0,
                  color: Colors.white,
                ),
              ),
              SizedBox(
                height: 30.0,
              ),
              Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: [
                  Image.asset(
                    "./assets/images/${this.image}",
                    scale: 4.0,
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    width: 30.0,
                  ),
                  Text(
                    "${this.temperature}°C",
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 96.0,
                      color: Colors.white,
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              SizedBox(
                height: 30.0,
              ),
              Text(
                this.status.toUpperCase(),
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 24.0,
                  color: Colors.white,
                ),
              ),
              SizedBox(
                height: 10.0,
              ),
              Text(
                "MIN / MAX : ${this.minTemperature.toString()} / ${this.maxTemperature.toString()}",
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 24.0,
                  color: Colors.white,
                ),
              ),
              SizedBox(
                height: 10.0,
              ),
              Text(
                "HUMIDITY : ${this.humidity}%",
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 24.0,
                  color: Colors.white,
                ),
              ),
              SizedBox(
                height: 30.0,
              ),
              ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: () async {
                  dynamic userInput =
                      await Navigator.pushNamed(context, "/search");
                  this.updateUI(
                    userInput: userInput.toString(),
                  );
                },
                style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                    vertical: 8.0,
                    horizontal: 16.0,
                  ),
                ),
                child: Text(
                  "Search by city name",
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 20.0,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: "The thing is, all the state variables are initialized using the setState() method inside the initState()".  You don't need that.  If you're in initState, your build should not have happened yet, so just *set* the state vars.  No need to call setState... that will trigger a new build(), and maybe that's what you're seeing.

Comment: Thanks. I fixed it. But it still crashes. :(

Comment: @JinwookKim any error on terminal ?

Comment: It reads, Unhandled Exception: dependOnInheritedWidgetOfExactType<_ModalScopeStatus>() or dependOnInheritedElement() was called before _MainScreenState.initState() completed.

Comment: Try to use a ```FutureBuilder``` and call the ```updateUI``` in future parameter

Answer (score 13, accepted):

if you want to use `Future` function in `initState` and want it run once and complete before `build`, please consider to use `WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback`, like

```
@override
void initState() {
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) async {
        await this.getWeatherData();
        setState(() { });
    });
}
```

and

```
@override
void initState() {
  WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) async {
    await this.updateUI();
    setState(() { });        
  });
}
```

`setState` should be used for rebuild the widget

Comment: SIMPLE AND CONCISE!

Comment: After 3 days of searching this solved my issue.

Comment: Brilliant! This feature is not well documented, and is extremely useful.  Thanks!

Comment: This answer may solve the problem (more or less), but it does not ensure the code in `initState` completes prior to `build` running. `addPostFrameCallback`, as the name implies "post frame", runs code _after_ the `build` method finishes. Instead, use `FutureBuilder` in your build method.